# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it - Socket Program

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

The problem that im facing is given in the Headline. 
This is where i am :

- Got a Socket Server up and running on Port 61911 :

  _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 61911));
- And that port (61911) is opened globally and set the Server IP Address to 192.168.1.2 (My PC)
- Firewall and Antivirus Programs are dealed well.
- Ran the Socket Server and got port open status from [YouGetSignal.com](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

Pic :

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/1777/x07w.png

- And while ^Checking, the Socket Server responded well, i **think** that means **Established** Connection to the Server im hosting.
- But when accessed through the Client, i get the error specified 
  'No Connection could be made...'

Here is the Code that I use for Connection in Client :

```
private static void LoopConnect()
    {
        while (!_client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {

                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("**PUBLIC IP**");
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip,61911);
                _client.Connect(remoteEP);
            }
            catch (SocketException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
    }
```

And this Code that handles Accepting in the Server :

```
private static void SetupServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up Server.. ");
        _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 61911));
        _server.Listen(4);
        Console.WriteLine("Server UP!");
        _server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
    }

    private static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _server.EndAccept(AR);
        _clients.Add(socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
        _server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
    }
```

So i think thats all the information regarding the problem i can give ..

*Evrything regarding Malware Protection, Firewalls, Port Forwarding.. is done.
*And port is open in `netstat -anb`

Solutions appreciated :)

EDIT : The client sends request and then the server acknowledges. But i think that doesnt reach the client. For which i should do something else in the router like porting from 'inside'. How is that possible ???

Comment: What happens if you connect locally?

Comment: It works well :) no problem at all :)

Comment: Then I suspect a router-setting mistake. Do you also forward that port from within the local net?

Comment: i dont think so. Cuz, the port is opened when checked through Yougetsignal.com,, and i got some response in my server console when checking through the website. This all means an established connection ryt ??

Comment: Where is the client running?

Comment: both are running on the same machine, but the client's parameter is set to connect to this machine's public ip. Can that cause a problem ?? I dont have another system here.. :(

Answer (score 1):

What happens is this:

1. Client tries to connect to public IP.
2. In doing so, it will connect to the gateway (which is your router)
3. Your router denies access on that port, because you only opened it from the **outside**, not the **inside**.

To test your application, just use your local IP (192.168.1.2). when deployed, you can use the outside address. You could also open the port forwarding from the inside in your router, but that would be outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: soo u mean place local ip in socket.connect (clientside) ??

Comment: Yes, where you have `IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("**PUBLIC IP**");`, yout put `IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("**LOCAL IP**");`

Comment: then how can i make the client access via public ip ? like what to do for the client to run when run on another machine on another network ??

Comment: Make that IP a setting, so you can change it. That's anyway smart to do, for example if you would move your server to another machine or if your public IP changes.

Comment: yea that can be done. But still, why the client cant connect to the server via 'internet' ??

Comment: The code is fine. It is your network setup that is causing trouble. I cannot go into complete detail of network management here.

Comment: is there any alternative method ? like it a server accessible globally via the public IP ?? I heard of WCF, is that a better option ?? *and my ISP dnt keep any restrictions on hosting.

Comment: can you give me a tag or method/process name into which i should look ? :)

Comment: I have given you a lot of tips and you don't seem to listen. You have to teach yourself some basic networking, routing and TCP/IP. You should be able to use Google by yourself.

Comment: Okay, now, i tried running the client from another PC, ie an online Virtual Machine, downloaded the client in it, given evry info regarding the server running here, and Voila it worked!!                                now what im asking is why it doesnt work when client and server is hosted from the same PC ??